# Generalizing variance inflation factor python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a generalized code for VIF to iterate over the VIF results one by one untill i reach the threshold of 10. The code is as follows:-

```
        variables = list(range(X.shape[1]))
        dropped = True
        while dropped:
            dropped = False
            vif = [variance_inflation_factor(X.iloc[:, variables].values, ix) for ix in variables]
            print('\n\nvif is: \n', vif)
            maxloc = vif.index(max(vif))
            if max(vif) > thresh:
                print('dropping \'' + X.iloc[:, variables].columns[maxloc] + '\' at index: ' + str(maxloc))
                X.drop(X.columns[variables[maxloc]], 1, inplace=True)
                variables = list(range(X.shape[1]))
                dropped = True

        print('\n\nRemaining variables:\n')
        print(X.columns[variables])
```

But as i am iterating and dropping values one by one it is dropping the intercept in the first iteration and in the second iteration VIF values calculated are totally different and wrong as VIF requires Intercept. I tried add_constant from statsmodels  but it creates an infinite loop by dropping intercept from each iterations. Please help me on this, any other generalized code for VIF is also appreciated.

Comment: you could just drop the intercept index from your `variables` so it is not removed

Comment: Can you please be more specific and let me know how i could do that?

Comment: `variables` is a list, so you can just delete the index corresponding to the intercept